# In JavaScript ES6, for-in loop and for-of loop, the variable i stops to exist after each iteration of the block?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, for-in-loop, for-of-loop

Typically I'd use a `let i` in the following first two cases:

```
> for (const i in ["red", "green", "blue"]) { console.log(i) }
0
1
2

> for (const i of ["red", "green", "blue"]) { console.log(i) }
red
green
blue

> for (const i = 0; i < 10; i++) { console.log(i) }
0
TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
```

But [the Mozilla documentation stated a `const` can be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).  So the `i` ceased to exist after the end of the block `{ console.log(i) }`?  Isn't that not true if it is the third case above?

Is it a subtle rule? The loop variable for `for ( in )` and `for ( of )` loop ceases to exist after the block, but for the `for (;;)` loop, it stays? It is somewhat subtle -- is it in any of the ES6 specs?

Comment: @Yaka: There is no "declaring i again and again". The constant is declared in the initialisation step, which only occurs once.

Answer (score 2):

The variable in each case does cease to exist after the loop. You can see it work as you expect if you use `let` instead of `const`.

```js
for (let i in ["red", "green", "blue"]) { console.log(i) }
for (let i of ["red", "green", "blue"]) { console.log(i) }
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { console.log(i) }
console.log(i); // error, because `i` is local
```

However, you cannot use `++` on a constant, which accounts for your error. The constant or variable in `for..of` and `for..in` constructs is recreated in each loop; but you can't do that with `for`.

However, if you don't try to modify the constant, it again works as expected:

```js
for (const i = [0]; i[0] < 10; i[0]++) { console.log(i[0]) }
console.log(i) // error, because `i` is local
```

Comment: I don't mean after the whole loop -- I mean after **each iteration** of `{ console.log(i) }`, the `i` ceases to exist, but for the `for (;;)` loop, the `i` doesn't cease to exist, so it is kind of subtle

Comment: Yes, I had a bit of a mind blowage on `for (const i in/of ...)`, where `i` is clearly local, and clearly changes, and yet clearly constant. But it is important to note that `for(;;)` is a very different construct from `for (let/const ... in/of ...)`, even if they share the keyword.

Answer (score -2):

If you need to limit the scope of the loop variable justo surround the loop with another block and use `let`.

```
{
    for (let i in ["red", "green", "blue"]) {console.log(i);}
}
console.log(i);
```

This way the last `console.log` will throw Reference error, because it's not defined in its scope